# How to add due date to Loan table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

```
public static void createLoan(Loan loan){

    Connection con = null;

    try {
        con = JDBCConnectionFactory.getInstance().getNewConnection();
        String sql = "";

        sql = "INSERT INTO loan (users_id, book_id, loan_date, loan_dueDate) "
                + "VALUES (?, ?, CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30))";
        PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        prep.setLong(1, loan.user.getDatabaseId());
        prep.setLong(2, loan.book.getDatabaseId());
```

Why can´t I use the `DATE_ADD` function to set a specific date? It just returns `Null`.

Comment: The question is unclear.  You show an insert query and talk about returning null.

Comment: In my database the column Loan_dueDate gets the value NULL, but it is supposed to get the DueDate?

Comment: What returns null? Is it the new entry in your database that says null in loan_dueDate? According to this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp you should add "DAY" in the end of "INTERVAL 30".

Comment: Thanks it helped. I simply forgot the keyword DAY at the end og the sql statement.

Comment: Worth adding what kind of database you're using? - this looks like MySQL syntax, other SQL implementations use slightly different versions of date_add.

Answer (score 0):

`DATEADD` Method example :

```
SELECT OrderId,DATEADD(day,45,OrderDate) AS OrderPayDate
FROM Orders
```

check this one : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp

Answer (score 0):

function `Date_Add` has signature `DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr unit)` you are missing the unit.

I tried with below sample data

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `NAME` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `loanduedate` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
) ;

 INSERT INTO person VALUES(4,'shirish',DATE_ADD(CURDATE() , INTERVAL 45 DAY));
```

and the insert went fine.

table has below data inserted successfully

```
    ID  NAME     loanduedate        
------  -------  -------------------
     4  shirish  2015-06-11 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

- [Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

```
DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr unit)
```

> - The **date** argument specifies the starting date or datetime value.
> - **expr** is an expression specifying the interval value to be added or subtracted from the starting date. expr is a string; it may start with a “-” for negative intervals.
> - **unit** is a keyword indicating the units in which the expression should be interpreted.

And for you, the problem is that *unit* is missing you should select it from the table of [unit value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), like `DAY`.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO loan (users_id, book_id, loan_date, loan_dueDate) "
                + "VALUES (?, ?, CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY))";
```